# Understanding Django CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE and CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS

Tags: django, iframe, cross-domain, csrf

Obviously I have a problem to understand the impact of Django (2.2.4) settings regarding CSRF parameters in a cross-domain environment.

As I have already noticed I have to set `SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None` if I want to place my Django application into an iframe of a website with another domain (e.g. Django app on foo.com and iframe on bar.com) in order to send forms on my Django application.

However what's about the CSRF parameters? After some trials I noticed that I can only send the Django form in the iframe if I also set `CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None`in the Django settings.

But what is the `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS` for? If I set the iframe domain (e.g. bar.com) into the list `['bar.com']` instead of `CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None` I can not send the form on my Django app in the iframe.

Could anybody explain in what case `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS` has any effect? Is it just usable in an environment with one domain and serveral subdomains?

Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 11):

Briefly: `CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE` affects browser behavior, while `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS` affects Django's behavior. You will need to make sure both are set appropriately.

The [`CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE) setting simply determines what [`SameSite`](https://owasp.org/www-community/SameSite) directive, if any, is used for the CSRF [`SetCookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie). That directive will then be used by the browser to determine whether or not to include the cookie in a request.

The [`CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#csrf-trusted-origins) setting is there to allow you to make exceptions to Django's default behavior of strictly checking the `Host` and `Referer` headers on incoming requests with CSRF protection. See [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#how-it-works) for more on this check.

So, when you didn't set `CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE` to  `None`, Django used its default value of `'Lax'`, which instructed the browser not to send the cookie cross-domain with unsafe requests (like `POST`). Since the cookie wasn't sent, `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS` was irrelevant.

Comment: Why would you use `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS` at all? Sounds like a security vulnerability.