# DRF set_cookie does not work when frontend is on localhost and backend is on a remote server

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt, django-cors-headers

I've created a DRF app which the backend is using jwt authentication with httpolnly cookies for authentication and it also uses a enforce_csrf for perventing csrf attacks.

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication import JWTAuthentication
from django.conf import settings

from rest_framework.authentication import CSRFCheck
from rest_framework import exceptions

def enforce_csrf(request):
    check = CSRFCheck()
    check.process_request(request)
    reason = check.process_view(request, None, (), {})
    print(reason)
    if reason:
         raise exceptions.PermissionDenied('CSRF Failed: %s' % reason)

class CookieBasedJWTAuthentication(JWTAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        header = self.get_header(request)
    
        if header is None:
            raw_token = request.COOKIES.get(settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE_ACCESS']) or None
        else:
            raw_token = self.get_raw_token(header)
        if raw_token is None:
            return None
        
        validated_token = self.get_validated_token(raw_token)
        enforce_csrf(request)
        return self.get_user(validated_token), validated_token
```

to pervent csrf attacks django set a cookie and also a 'csrftokenmiddleware' and compares them.

here is the sample code for setting csrf cookie and token:

```
class SetCSRFToken(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    def get(self, request):
        response = Response() 
        csrf.get_token(request)
        response.status_code = status.HTTP_200_OK
        csrf_secret = csrf.get_token(request)
        response.set_cookie(
            key = 'csrftoken', 
            value = request.META["CSRF_COOKIE"],
            expires = settings.SIMPLE_JWT['REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME'],
            path= settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE_PATH'],
            secure = settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE_SECURE'],
            httponly = False,
            samesite = 'Lax'
          )
        response.data = {"status": "CSRF cookie set", 'csrfmiddlewaretoken':request.META["CSRF_COOKIE"]}

        return response
```

i also set :

```
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS=  True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```

the code works perfect when both frontend and backend are on the localhost, but when i run the backend on a remote server, the cookies are not set but the browser receives the Response to request.

[when frontend is on the same host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5K8R.png)

[when backend on remote server and frontend on localhsot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XS8xM.png)

[this is the console result for both cases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6n0sS.png)

this is the settings, I've tried using CSRF options, but still not setting the cookie, what is weired is when i call out to my apiView from browser(rather than javascript) the cookie is being set.

settings.py:

```
    """
Django settings for core project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.0.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os
from .info import *
from datetime import timedelta

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

EMAIL_USE_TLS = EMAIL_USE_TLS
EMAIL_HOST = EMAIL_HOST
EMAIL_HOST_USER =  EMAIL_HOST_USER
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD =  EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD
EMAIL_PORT =  EMAIL_PORT 
FRONTEND_URL = FRONTEND_URL

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-yzvg4k4r0%*3001&oo&up*@-yvcq(k@tpsdi^g=*ql#zvtogav'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['myip', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1']
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None
CSRF_TRUESTED_ORIGINS =['myip', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1'] 

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'api',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    'users',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'core.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'core.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS=  True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://myip:3000",
    "http://127.0.0.1:3000",
    "http://localhost:3000",
]


'''
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    )
}
'''
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ]  ,
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        #'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
        'users.authentication.CookieBasedJWTAuthentication',
    )
}
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.DearUser'

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=60),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': True,
    'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': True,
    'UPDATE_LAST_LOGIN': False,
    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer','JWT'),
    'AUTH_HEADER_NAME': 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION',
    'ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'SIGNING_KEY': SECRET_KEY,
    'USER_ID_FIELD': 'email',
    'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'email',


    # cookie based jwt settings
    'AUTH_COOKIE_ACCESS':'ACCESS',
    'AUTH_COOKIE_REFRESH':'REFRESH',
    'AUTH_COOKIE_SECURE': False, 
    'AUTH_COOKIE_HTTP_ONLY' : True,
    'AUTH_COOKIE_PATH': '/',
    'AUTH_COOKIE_SAMESITE': 'None', #Strict

}
```

Comment: Are you using a secure cookie ? When not using the same domain, you should check cookies options here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#session-cookie-samesite. Browser also might check http|https when using secure

Comment: This is a Dev server and I've set both samesite and secure to False, do you think i should buy a domain and setup an https server?, or is there any way to make a virtual server with static public ip address to run django DRF as https(just for my development tests)?

Comment: Can you share your settings.py (without any secrets on it please ^^') ?
Check the CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE and SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE, ALLOWED_HOST and CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS , also, if you have the requests (on your browser with the list of headers) ? You should not buy a domain for that.

Comment: I added the settings.py

I've tried using CSRF options, but still not setting the cookie, what is weired is when i call out to my apiView from browser(rather than javascript) the cookie is being set.

Comment: I also put both of them(front and back) on the virtual server and it worked as expected!

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57569508/understanding-django-csrf-cookie-samesite-and-csrf-trusted-origins, I guess you should not set SameSite to None.

Comment: yes, i changed it to samesite=Strict and secure=False since i dont have https, but still have the same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it!
First make sure you got everything right in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46412839/18327111

because django corsheaders middleware is checking the below if, make sure to have the following settings:

```
if conf.CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS and not conf.CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS:
    response[ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN] = "*"
else:
    response[ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN] = origin
```

new settings:

```
from corsheaders.defaults import default_headers
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS=  False
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://yourip_or_domain:3000",
    "http://127.0.0.1:3000",
    "http://localhost:3000",
]
#making sure CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS  is not "*"
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = list(default_headers) + ['Set-Cookie']
```

in case you are not using django session authentication(as i do) and want to bypass it add the following settings

```
CSRF_USE_SESSIONS = False
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None
```

and the main reason it failed: this is copied from chrome developer tools and mozila also have this warning:

> Because a cookie’s SameSite attribute was not set or is invalid, it
> defaults to SameSite=Lax, which prevents the cookie from being sent in
> a cross-site request. This behavior protects user data from
> accidentally leaking to third parties and cross-site request forgery.
> Resolve this issue by updating the attributes of the cookie:
>
> Specify **SameSite=None** and **Secure** if the cookie should be sent in
> cross-site requests. This enables third-party use.
>
> Specify **SameSite=Strict** or **SameSite=Lax** if the cookie should not be
> sent in cross-site requests.

so if you want to access cross origin, the only way is using an https and SameSite=None, otherwise you have to deploy your api and backend on the same domain

Note that http and https are considered as different domain and are cross-origin
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite#samesitenone_requires_secure

> Cookies from the same domain are no longer considered to be from the
> same site if sent using a different scheme (http: or https:).